# info exists command in Tcl returns an error

Tags: tcl

I wrote the following code in itcl

```
if {[info exists ::xtg::triggers::match$arg]} {
    eval delete object ::xtg::triggers::match$arg 
}
```

this code should check if there exists an object of name ::xtg::triggers::match$arg and delete it if it exists.
The problem is that I get the following error in my shell :
" command "match0" already exists in namespace "::xtg::Triggers" "
and not 1 or 0 as written in the manual of info exists command.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`info exists`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/info.htm#M14) checks for existing variables, not commands (incl. object commands).

Try:

```
if {[info commands ::xtg::triggers::match$arg] ne ""} {
     # ...
}
```

You might also want to consider Itcl's `info objects`:

```
if {::xtg::triggers::match$arg in [info objects]} {
     # ...
}
```

or

```
if {[info objects ::xtg::triggers::match$arg] ne ""} {
     # ...
}
```

(assuming that you call `[info objects]` for the correct namespace scope)